# how to add minimum text in textfield

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have three types of text fields. in that I need only minimum numbers only . below code I write-in but its not working. help me

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{ 
    if (country.text.length <= 4) {
        return YES;
    }

    if(code.text.length<=4 ) {
        return YES;
    }

    if(textPhone.text.length<=10) {
        return YES;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE`?

Comment: So basically you always return `YES`, so what exactly is not working?

Comment: Why do you even have these `if statements` if you always return `YES` this seems absolutely pointless.

Comment: when i click one text field another two text field not working

Comment: You probably intended to `return NO` on your last line (which would still be wrong), but if you're looking into validation [this will make your life easier](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is flawed here. You don't even base your checks on which field is edited.

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{ 

    // Allow backspace anyway
    if (range.length == 0)
        return YES;

    if (textField == country)
        return (country.text.length <= 4);

    else if (textField == code)
        return (code.text.length <= 4);

    else if (textField == textPhone)
        return (textPhone.text.length <= 10);

    // Default for all other fields
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: its working fine bro.. but when i enter   4 numbers i cant delete the numbers.. when i enter 3 numbers i can able to delete. ?

Comment: To allow the backspace "character", you need to check first if `range.length == 0`, then return YES (before all other checks). I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First off this seems absolutely pointless since you return `YES` in every case so why even bother with the `if statement` but if you insist on doing it try any of the below.

After you have initialized your `UITextFields` set the following

```
... Initilization code for country, textPhone and code.
[country setTag:1001];
[code setTag:1002];
[textPhone setTag:1003];
```

and in your `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method do

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{ 
    switch([textField tag]) {
        case 1001:
                  // Do whatever 
                  return (textField.text.length <= 4);
        case 1002:
                  // Do whatever
                  return (textField.text.length <= 4);
        case 1003:
                  // Do whatever
                  return (textField.text.length <= 10);
        default:
                return YES;
    }
}
```

Are if you want to do it with an if statement still try

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{ 
    if((([textField tag] == 1001 || [textField tag] == 1002) && [textField text].length <= 4) || ([textField tag] == 1003 && [textField text].length <= 10)) {
        return ((([textField tag] == 1001 || [textField tag] == 1002) && [textField text].length <= 4) || ([textField tag] == 1003 && [textField text].length <= 10));
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: No need for `break`s after `return`!

Comment: @Cyrille very true as it will never be reached, edited.